# Angular Server Side Rendering (SSR) and mapbox-gl library are not compatible?

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, mapbox-gl

Mapbox-gl is a javascript client library that is currently blocking the process of server side rendering on our Angular 8 application due to intensive usage of Browser Api components such as window, document, etc...

We don't want to render the map on server side but simply want the application to run without error.
ReferenceError: self is not defined

Is there a way to use isPlatformServer from @angular/common to avoid loading the library on server side?

The problem seems to come from the library itself
node_modules\mapbox-gl\dist\mapbox-gl.js

Comment: For those who fall on this question, map-box has released a fix in their latest version. https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/releases/tag/v1.11.0. This prevent the eager loading of "window" and "document" variable.